# Does MongoDB support the following operation atomically?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have the following schema

```
t = {name: 'John', reviews: [{sid: 1, comment: 'Great', rating: 4}, {sid: 2, comment: 'Awesome', rating: 5}]}
db.teacher.save(t)
db.teacher.find()
```

Now student with sid 2 updates the rating to 4.  Are there any in built operations to do this atomically?  At the moment I retrieve the entire document, manipulate reviews manually and then $set the entire reviews array.  It works but feels a bit heavy handed.  I have looked at all of the atomic operators and a lot of them come close but from what I can see none of them quite do what I'm asking.  Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB, as many other DBMS, implements [update](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating) command:

```
db.teacher.update({'reviews.sid': 2}, {$set: {'reviews.$.rating': 4}}, false, true);
```

As a sidenote, I often recommend this [cheatsheet](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart) for people who are experienced with SQL, but just have started using Mongo. )

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've tried your query but I'm getting 'can't append to array using string field name' do you get the same on your side?

Comment: Argh, a stupid mistake from me. ( Updated the answer, now works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can directly update only the key you want using [$set](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set) and referencing the key using [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29).